# Give an example that shows that the cut property does not hold if we replace the real numbers by rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics

Trying to find an example where we have two disjoint nonempty sets of rational numbers A and B so that $A \cup B = Q$ and every element of A is less than every element of B, but that there is no rational number $r \in Q$ satisfying $x \le r$ whenever $x \in A$ and $x \ge r$ whenever $x \in B$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A:= \{x \in \mathbb{Q}: x > \sqrt{2}\}$

Let $B:= \{x \in \mathbb{Q}: x < \sqrt{2}\}$

Comment: @AnuragA Sure! Corrected!

Comment: You should interchange $A$ and $B$ because OP's requirement is that every element of $A$ is less than every element of $B$.

Comment: @David It is as simple as that? Would it work then for any square root, like $\sqrt3$ or $\sqrt5$?

Comment: @RichardSmith Sure! It would work also for $\mathbb{\pi}$ or any other irrational number you can think of. Can you check it yourself?